# Unable to activate Dart Devtools in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, devtools

I have no idea about "Activaing Dart DevTools". I had not get any response for a long time!
[andorid studio progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Ufz.png)

Comment: Stay calm, that is not an error. You can restart your IDE if it relaxing you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Android Studio : `Tools` -> `flutter` -> `Open Flutter dev tool`
- VS Code: Search for `Dart:` in the command palette, then click on `open DevTools`

Answer (score 3):

Click on this in your android studio [image]

Then you will get a link like in this picture
[image]

At the same time browser will open this
[image]
There you just paste your generated link and connect

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio, go to the terminal and write the command `dart devtools`. Then wait for a while. It will open a tab in your browser and it will give you an address like this `Serving DevTools at http://127.0.0.1:9234` that you need to write as the URL to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it easier by clicking on the `Open Flutter DevTools` button that shows in the Run console in Android Studio. It's blue, on the right of the Hot Reload and the Hot Restart.

Answer (score 1):

for new versions of flutter plugin and android studio, there is no icon for Dart Devtools, instead, the terminal will give you a link like:

> The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is
> available at:
> http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1:62203/l8yx-VW8bgA=/

you just click on it to open the browser.